# the page heading isn't connected

Tags: css

please help me with the website heading here. Please look at my picture below:
[image]

I have no idea why it is like that. I just use simple css and it became like that and similar as the buttom. The same thing happens as the bottom part of the page. Please help!Not sure why it's like that.

Comment: From the look of the url, perhaps this is homework? Best to tag it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following CSS to override default padding.

```
html,body{padding:0;}
```

Comment: sorry that still doesn't work. it still display the same thing. please help!

Comment: Oh no worries now, it works now. I added html,body{padding:0;margin:0;} then it worked. Thanks alot!